# Get a country list in a determinated language

Tags: java, country-codes

I'm already able to get a list of countries, but the name are desplayed in my language (italian). I need them to be desplayed in english, this is what I have right now (This code is not mine, I copied it from the web)

```
String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(500);
    for (String countryCode : locales) {

        Locale obj = new Locale("en", countryCode);
        list.add(obj.getDisplayCountry());
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
    country = new String[list.size()];
    country = list.toArray(country);
```

Thank you  =)

Answer (score 5):

You should specify the output locale with [`Locale.getDisplayCountry(Locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayCountry%28java.util.Locale%29) and something like

```
String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(500); // <-- List interface, and diamond
                                          //     operator.
Locale outLocale = new Locale("EN", "us"); // <-- English US
for (String countryCode : locales) {
    Locale obj = new Locale("en-us", countryCode);
    list.add(obj.getDisplayCountry(outLocale));
}
Collections.sort(list);
String[] country = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(country));
```